# Blocking incoming and outgoing calls using mobile device management in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-telephony

Is there any options to block incoming and outgoing calls using mobile device management in ios

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to block incoming or outgoing calls and/or text messages.